# como acessar um elemento do shadowDom usando D3.js e Polymer

Tags: html, d3.js, polymer

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer um programa para de denhar um grafico, porém preciso apagar os grafico e desenha-lo novamente sempre que atualizo.
Estou utilizando D3.js pra manipular o svg e polymer pois estou criando um componente web. De forma resumida meu código está assim:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"
charset="utf-8"></script>

<dom-module id="soma-linechart">



<template>

  <svg id="mySvg" width="960" height="500"></svg>

</template>



<script> 

class SomaLinechart extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'soma-linechart'; }


  ready(){
    super.ready()

    var svg = d3.select(this.$.mySvg),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("id","myg");

  }   
}
customElements.define(SomaLinechart.is, SomaLinechart);


</script>
</dom-module>
```

para acessar o elemento svg eu uso o comando do d3:

```
var a = d3.select(this.$.mysvg)
```

pelo fato de estar trabalhando no shadow DOM, porém gostaria de saber como acessar o elemento g que eu criei, pois a mesma forma de escrita não funciona.